# Keyframe animations

Tags: html, css

I am a bit confused on how keyframes work exactly in this demo. Whats confusing me is that 0% and 100% are not defined but 25% and 75% are. But at 0% the 25% keyframe is active. I thought it wouldn't be active until 25% through the animation until it hits the 75% keyframe. Also when does the 75% keyframe stop 100%? If you could explain exactly what is happening it would be appreciated. I hope this question is clear. Thanks.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

.pulse {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.pulse:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="pulse">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi if you don't need animation to happen then add

```
@keyframes <animation name>
{

  0%,25%
  {
  animation here
  }

  75%,100%
  {
  animation here
  }

}
```

what happens here is animation don't start up-to 25%, from 25% to 75% animation plays and stops after 75% until it reaches 100%